# No libffmpeg.so for command line arguments after building FFMPEG for android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have followed the tutorial [roman10](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/comment-page-4/#comment-2573) and the build finishes just fine. But I have .so files for everything except ffmpeg.so(or I see it as libffmpeg.so in some examples). So I dont know how to get that. Do I need to change a configure option? Am am using the following configure options:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=$HOME/Desktop/adt/android-ndk-r9
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --enable-shared \
    --disable-static \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-symver \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

Do I even need the libffmpeg.so in order to call the command line arguments?

Answer (score 4):

With "--disable-ffmpeg" you're actually telling it not to compile the bit you're looking for. It won't compile ffmpeg.c, just the stuff you've specified. You can use the libav* libraries directly (well, you'll need to make a jni wrapper...), but if you want the ffmpeg bit you can invoke with command line arguments then remove that line.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I ended up doing is removing that line and invoking ffmpeg from the command line.

Comment: Glad it helped. Do you mean you had to do some kind of Runtime.exec call out to the ffmpeg executable? If so, it's worth noting you could still build a libffmpeg.so if you wanted to and call main() through JNI... You just need to relink the libs you have and the top level object files (ffmpeg.o, ffmpeg_filter.o, cmdutils.o) as a shared lib instead of the executable it builds by default.

Comment: I think the list of stuff you'd want to link would be (order is important, and substitute your output paths for these variables, or define the variables):

$FFMPEG_SRC/*.o $LIB_OUT/libavdevice.a $LIB_OUT/libavformat.a $LIB_OUT/libavfilter.a $LIB_OUT/libavcodec.a $LIB_OUT/libswscale.a $LIB_OUT/libavutil.a $LIB_OUT/libavresample.a $LIB_OUT/libswresample.a -o $LIB_OUT/libffmpeg.so